# A way of shortening my URL string

Tags: javascript, php

I have a string that represents an 812 bit file as a hex string. I'm trying to pass this in some way to a php script that will force a download of the file. The problem is that the URL string is too long. The length of just the hex string is 1624. Is there some sort of encoding or encryption I can use to shorten the string and still be able to get the expected result on the php side? I have tried sending json with an Ajax request, but I don't believe I can force a download that way.

JS:

```
var cfg = '';
for (var x = 0; x < relayBytes.length; x++)
{
    var str = relayBytes[x].toString(16);
    if (str.length === 1) str = '0' + str;
    cfg += str;
}
window.location = '../script.php?relay=' + cfg;
```

relayBytes is an int array with a length of 812.

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/octetstream; name="file.txt"');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="file.txt"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.txt"');
echo $_GET['relay'];
?>
```

Comment: You could just switch over to POST

Comment: Why must the string be that long? Can you use a shorter string, then server side link up the shorter string with the longer string?

Comment: also you could create a txt file and just send the link to it.

Comment: @Volkan Each byte is more or less editable by the user. There are an astronomical amount of combinations. I can't really just link a file.

Comment: I mean, create the file dynamically with ajax, then use window.location to send the user to another php script, where you force him to download.

Comment: Base64 encoding will reduce the size from 1624 bytes to just under 1100 bytes. But the best way to compress/encode this data would be one customised for the task.

Comment: @Volkan Creating a file or a temporary file on the server side is not something I want to do. I will need to download the response as a file without creating one server side.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Using window.btoa(cfg), the string went from 1624 to 2168 in length.

Comment: @JaredPrice You've Base64 encoded `str` rather than the original string (`relayBytes`).

Comment: Ahh I see. Well knowing what I do about the possible combinations, I've created a way to encode a string representing the int array with the length of 812 into a string of length 288. This looks like it will work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the POST method to pass the data from one page to another page and also there many no of 3rd party services which  provide you URL shortner service. You can also use their service but I will prefer you to use form post method to pass the data.